# How to tie your JComboBox to search an outside ArrayList?

Tags: java, user-interface, search, arraylist, jcombobox

Hi guys, this is my first time posting here but I've got a lot of help searching through this site before!  Right now I am pretty new to Java so bear with me if I do not use the correct terminology, but I'm stuck at a certain point.

I'm trying to create a **GUI** whose function is to search through a `"database"` of `cars`. I have made an object of type `Automobile`, which I have then placed into an `ArrayList` in order to create my `"database"`.  Now from there, I have created a `"search"` function which breaks the objects of the `ArrayList` down into an array of `strings`.

Next, I have created a **GUI** with several `JComboBoxes` and `buttons`, this where my issue is, I do not know how to tie the `database` to the **GUI** so it can search through it.  Do I need to include the entire `database` within the method where I created the **GUI**?  How do I go about having my **GUI** interact with the separate class?  I am also unsure how to go about converting my `"search"` function into an `ActionEvent` for the `JComboBox`, it is my understanding that what I need to do is have the string from the drop down list match the string from my `"search"` function but how do I marry the two together?

I am largely self taught, so if this is the wrong place to ask these questions I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

I only included a small portion of the database, but every part of my GUI so far, I'm hoping for some criticism of my code or if anyone knows a more efficient way of building the **GUI** and could let me know

Thanks! 
-Robert

My `"database"` with simple search function

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AutomobileTest
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
 Automobile car1 = new 
 Automobile("Acura","Integra","Green","Manual","Coupe",1999,200000,3000);

 Automobile car2 = new 
 Automobile("Acura","MDX","Silver","Automatic","SUV",2017,1865,56000);

 Automobile car3 = new 
 Automobile("Audi","RS4","Red","Manual","Sedan",2007,63000,19000);

 ArrayList<Automobile> dataBase = new ArrayList<Automobile>();

 dataBase.add(car1);
 dataBase.add(car2);
 dataBase.add(car3);

 String[] search = new String[dataBase.size()];
 String key;

 for(int i=0; i<search.length; i++)
 search[i] = dataBase.get(i).toString();

 for(int i=0; i<search.length; i++)
 {
   key = search[i].toString();
   if(key.contains("Audi")) //action event for dropdown list
   {
     System.out.println(key);
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

**My GUI**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CarGUIMethod extends JFrame
{
 private JFrame frame;
 private JPanel makePanel;
 private JPanel modelPanel;
 private JPanel colorPanel;
 private JLabel makeLabel;
 private JLabel modelLabel;
 private JLabel colorLabel;
 private JComboBox make;
 private JComboBox model;
 private JComboBox color;
 private JButton makeBtn;
 private JButton modelBtn;
 private JButton colorBtn;


public CarGUIMethod()
{
 setTitle("Search For Cars");
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 setSize(500, 400);
 setLocation(300, 150);

 make_Panel();
 add(makePanel);
 setVisible(true);

}

private void make_Panel()
{
 String[] makes = 
         {"Any","Acura","Audi","BMW","Ford","Ferrari","GMC","Honda",
                  "Lamborghini","Mercedes","Nissan","Porsche","Toyota" };

 makePanel = new JPanel();
 makePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(makePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
 makePanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30,30)));

 makeLabel = new JLabel("Select the make");
 makeBtn = new JButton("OK");
 make = new JComboBox<String>(makes);

 makeLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

 make.setMaximumSize(make.getPreferredSize());
 make.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

 make.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
 {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
     {
         JComboBox<String> select = (JComboBox<String>)event.getSource();
         String selectedMake = (String) select.getSelectedItem();
     }
  });


 makeBtn.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
 //makeBtn.addActionListener(new MakeButtonListener());

 makePanel.add(makeLabel);
 makePanel.add(make);
 makePanel.add(makeBtn);


  /////
 String[] models = { "Any" };

 modelPanel = new JPanel();
 modelPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(modelPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
 makePanel.add(modelPanel);
 modelPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30,30)));

 modelLabel = new JLabel("Select the model");
 model = new JComboBox<String>(models);
 modelBtn = new JButton("OK");

 model.setMaximumSize(model.getPreferredSize());
 model.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

 modelBtn.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

 modelPanel.add(modelLabel);
 modelPanel.add(model);
 modelPanel.add(modelBtn);


 ////
String[] colors =
   {"Any","Blue","Black","Red","Green","White","Yellow","Silver","Purple" };

colorPanel = new JPanel();
colorPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(colorPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
makePanel.add(colorPanel);
colorPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30,30)));


colorLabel = new JLabel("Select the color");
color = new JComboBox<String>(colors);
colorBtn = new JButton("OK");

colorLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

color.setMaximumSize(color.getPreferredSize());
color.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

colorBtn.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

colorPanel.add(colorLabel);
colorPanel.add(color);
colorPanel.add(colorBtn);

}


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     new CarGUIMethod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I have turned my search into a method so now I can call it with a button, but it returns "null" after printing the results.  Did I write this method correct?

```
public String model(ArrayList<Automobile> dataBase)
{
  search = new String[dataBase.size()];
  boxText = "Honda";// boxText will be the JComboBox text

  for(int i=0; i<search.length; i++)
  search[i] = dataBase.get(i).toString();

  for(int i=0; i<search.length; i++)
  {
    key = search[i].toString();
    if(key.contains(boxText))//<<<<<< boxText 
    {
      System.out.println(key);
    }
   }
   return key;
  }
}
```